# Show that $\alpha c+\beta b+\gamma a\geq 3\beta-3\gamma-\alpha$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Each root of the polynomial $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$  is  real and  not greater than $1$. Prove that $$\alpha c+\beta b+\gamma a\geq 3\beta-3\gamma-\alpha$$ where $0<\alpha<\beta<\frac {\alpha+\gamma}{2} .$

---

We are trying to solve this contest question with my son.  I don't have a strong idea in mind.  However, I still have some trivial progress . We have $x_1\leq 1$ and $x_2\leq 1$ and $x_3\leq 1$ . By Vieta's formulas $$
\begin{aligned} x_1+x_2+x_3&=-a\\ x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3&=b\\ x_1x_2x_3&=-c
\end{aligned}
$$

So, we get $-a\leq 3$ or $a\geq -3$. However, we can not derive any information about $x_1x_2x_3$, since we don't know the sign of the roots. For instance, to write $-c=x_1x_2x_3\leq 1$ is obviously not correct . Similarly, I could not derive any useful information about the coefficient $b$ . Here, we left the question.  Because we couldn't make any further progress.

Comment: When you write $0<\alpha<\beta<\frac {\alpha+\gamma}{2} $ should it be interpreted as if it was prefixed by "for any triple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ such that ... " ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes for all possible triple. I just translated the question into English .

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes of course .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
\begin{align*}
 p &= (1 - x_1) + (1 - x_2) + (1 - x_3), \\
 q &= (1 - x_1)(1 - x_2) + (1 - x_2)(1 - x_3) + (1 - x_3)(1 - x_1), \\
 r &= (1 - x_1)(1 - x_2)(1 - x_3).
\end{align*}
Then $p, q, r \ge 0$.

Using Vieta's formula, we have
$$a = p - 3, \quad b = q - 2p + 3, \quad c = r - q + p - 1.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\alpha c+\beta b+\gamma a - (3\beta-3\gamma-\alpha)\\
 ={}& \alpha(r - q + p - 1) + \beta (q - 2p + 3) + \gamma (p - 3)\\
 ={}& (\alpha + \gamma - 2\beta)p + (\beta - \alpha)q + \alpha r\\
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: I like your approach better because it makes quick work of the expression, instead of having to work backwards to what the coefficients should be.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks. Your solution is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the transformation $ y = 1-x$, so that the roots are $ \geq 0$ (which tends to be easier to deal with).

This gives us $x^3  - (a+3) x^2 + (2a+b+3) x -(1+a+b+c) = 0 $, so $ a+3, 2a+b+3, 1+a+b+c$ are all non-negative.

The goal is to write the given expression $\alpha (c - 1) + \beta (b + 3) + \gamma (a + 3) \geq 0$ in terms of these alongside the condition $\gamma + \alpha \geq 2 \beta \geq 2 \alpha$. The guess is that we can write it as $ (a+3) A + (2a+b+3) B + (1+a+b+c) C \geq 0$, for some non-negative $A, B, C$.

Finally, observe that the expression is equal to $(a+3) (\gamma  - 2\beta + \alpha) + (2a+b+3) (\beta - \alpha ) + (1+a+b+c)(\alpha - 0 )$, hence it is $ \geq 0$.

Note: This involves some guess work / working backwards, but there isn't that many things to try. EG $A$ needs a $\gamma$ term, and $\gamma - 2\beta + \alpha$ was a natural thing to try. Then $B$ needs a $\beta$ term, so we use $\beta - \alpha$, and finally verify that $ C = \alpha$ works out.

Answer (score 0):

A geometrical approach :

Attach to each polynomial with all-real roots $<1$ the triple of its coefficients $d=(c,b,a)$ (we have reasons for reversing the order ; it will become clear later). Let $P$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$ of all such triples.

Besides, the set of all triples $\delta=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ constrained by

$$0<\alpha<\beta<\frac {\alpha+\gamma}{2}$$

defines another subset $Q$ which is a (unbounded) polyhedron.

The constraint to be established, written under the form :

$$\alpha (c+1)+\beta (b-3) + \gamma (a+3) \ge 0$$

expresses that a certain dot product is positive :

$$\delta . (d - d_0) \ge 0 \ \ \text{where} \ \ d_0=(-1,3,-3)$$

And indeed, this $d_0$ is a remarquable "point" of set $P$ because it corresponds to extremal polynomial

$$x^3-3x^2+3x-1=(x-1)^3$$

(with all its roots at the limit of the authorized domain).

It remains to have a better understanding of what the sets $P$ and $Q$ look like.

(for example by realizing a simulation in order to build conjectures). Up to you...

For example, if the set $Q$ was the tangent plane in $d_0$ to the set $P$ (which is not the case !), we could conclude at the positivity of the dot product.